# How do I add a behavior to ApplicationBarIconButton in C#?

Tags: windows-phone-7, behavior, application-bar

I am attempting to add items to an application bar with behavoirs.

In xaml they look like:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
  <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True"
                          IsMenuEnabled="True">
      <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="Save" 
                                      IconUri="/resources/icons/appbar.check.rest.png"
                                      Text="Save"  />
      <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="Cancel"
                                      IconUri="/resources/icons/appbar.cancel.rest.png"
                                      Text="Cancel"  />
  </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
  <Behaviors:ApplicationBarIconButtonCommand TextKey="Save" 
                                             CommandBinding="{Binding SaveEventSetupCommand}" />
  <Behaviors:ApplicationBarIconButtonCommand TextKey="Cancel" 
                                             CommandBinding="{Binding CancelEventSetupCommand}" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

For multi language support I need to add something like:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Localizedresources.lblCourse, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

to each button. It would appear that this cannot be done in xaml, hence the use of code.

The button is added in this code:

```
ApplicationBarIconButton appBarSaveButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(
            new Uri("/resources/icons/appbar.check.rest.png", UriKind.Relative)) 
            { Text = "Test" };

ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarSaveButton);
```

I just can't figure how to add the behavior. This is my start point:

```
WP7Contrib.View.Controls.Behaviors.ApplicationBarIconButtonCommand 
            ibc = new WP7Contrib.View.Controls.Behaviors.ApplicationBarIconButtonCommand 
{ TextKey = "Test" };
```

Basically I am looking for a working sample if anyone can oblige.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of behavior? I'm afriad it cannot be done, since ApplicationBar is not Silverlight control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Matt's answer this is my solution:

Add this at the top of the xaml page:

```
xmlns:Preview="clr-namespace:Phone7.Fx.Preview;assembly=Phone7.Fx.Preview"
```

and this inside the Grid at the bottom:

```
    <Preview:BindableApplicationBar x:Name="AppBar" BarOpacity="1.0" IsVisible="{Binding IsBarVisible}" >
        <Preview:BindableApplicationBarIconButton 
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
            Text="{Binding Path=Localizedresources.lblSave, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
            IconUri="/resources/icons/appbar.check.rest.png" />
        <Preview:BindableApplicationBarIconButton 
            Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"
            Text="{Binding Path=Localizedresources.lblCancel, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" 
            IconUri="/resources/icons/appbar.cancel.rest.png" />
    </Preview:BindableApplicationBar>
```

References:
http://blog.humann.info/post/2010/08/27/How-to-have-binding-on-the-ApplicationBar.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/CommandToAppBarWP7.aspx?display=Mobile

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the **Text** property of an `ApplicationBarIconButton` to a resource in XAML, which you've already worked out. To create a behavior and attached it in code you use code similar to the following (modified from an app I'm working on right now):

```
((ApplicationBarIconButton)this.ApplicationBar.Buttons[0].Text = Strings.NewContact;
var newBehavior = new ApplicationBarButtonNavigation
{
    ButtonText = Strings.NewContact,
    NavigateTo = new Uri("/views/ContactView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
};
Interaction.GetBehaviors(this).Add(newBehavior);
```

The principal is the same for your scenario: create the behavior, and then use `Interaction.GetBehaviors(this).Add(yourBehavior);`

**NOTE:** In the above examples **this** refers to the code-behind for the view and is not in the view model.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely make the ApplicationBar bindable by using the wrapper from http://blog.humann.info/post/2010/08/27/How-to-have-binding-on-the-ApplicationBar.aspx

Not sure about adding commands but this shoudl be possible with the same technique.